# The volume "Filesystem root" has only 0 bytes disk space remaining

Tags: partitioning, gparted, root

I am a new Ubuntu user and it appears as though my root partition is already full. My root partition is 480G large from GParted which seems abnormally large when compared to what I have seen on other forums.  I am not sure what I should do to fix my problem.  I have seen some people say rearrange the partition sizes through GParted... any recommendations on how to fix this?

[This is the output from the GParted window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5IgT.png)

Comment: You could try `df -hi | grep sda`  (disk.free -human output -inode info, grep'd to limit output; ie. sda only.   You didn't give the command you used that gave the error (which you should copy into your question; headings due to size get pushed off screen on some devices) and it maybe you ran out of inodes.  If you delete a file in use, the file entry is erased; but inodes are only freed once no longer in use (ie. delay before they're available; windows being single-user won't allow deletion of file in use; unix started as a multi-user OS so will & handles detail when it can).

Comment: `df -hi | grep  '/dev/sd'`, please. Not all hard disks are `/dev/sda`.